# Delete after subquery and return results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Right now I have the following SQL statement that I'm calling in PHP:

```
SELECT * FROM activity WHERE id=(
    SELECT activity_id FROM session_notifications
    WHERE session_id='{$session}');
```

This pulls table data from activities that are referenced in the session_notification table. All good. Now, is there an easy way to do this, but also in the same statement delete all of the rows returned by checking session_notifications?

** Edit: To be more clear, I do not want to delete the activity since I'll need that information. I want to delete the rows in session_notifications that were hit. Why? Because I don't want anything to have been added in afterwards. However, I might be okay since SQL tables are thread safe, yes?

Comment: You cannot issue a SELECT and DELETE statement in one. You have to send a new query for the DELETE statement.

Comment: Advise: to avoid errors when session_notifications has duplicated ID,  use IN instead of = : WHERE id IN (SELECT activity_id FROM session_notifications WHERE session_id='{$session}');. Does not answer your question, but will make your code better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure you will delete the records shown in the select, you must use a transaction.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM activity WHERE id IN (
    SELECT activity_id FROM session_notifications
    WHERE session_id='{$session}');
DELETE FROM activity WHERE id IN (
    SELECT activity_id FROM session_notifications
    WHERE session_id='{$session}');
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Great. I'll try this out as soon as I get back to my server.

Comment: I realized that I might not have been clear. This is more or less the reverse of what I want. If it were simply running the statement once with a select and once with a delete I'd be fine even without a transaction.

What I need to do is delete the session_notifications that were hit with that statement.

Comment: I think that what you would need is a trigger firing upon SELECT on that table, but that is not supported (yet) by MySQL. In addition, you normally cannot delete the row that fired the trigger (mutating table). As far as I understand your requirement, it can only be implemented in your code (php in this case) using a transaction. If the select always return 1 row only, you could create a MYSQL procedure returning the data and then deleting the record, and call the procedure from your (php) code instead of a select..

Comment: I think I've decided to go with locking the session_notifications table while performing the query and delete and then unlocking it. I wanted to avoid that and avoid back and forth data transactions through the stream as much as possible to keep things efficient, but I think this will work alright.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in doing this with one atomic statement. Use a transaction instead:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT …;
DELETE …;
COMMIT;
```

---

BTW be advised to use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of introducing a SQL injection with something like `WHERE session_id='{$session}'`.

Comment: I'll make a note to switch over. I suppose even in cases where you have complete control over the data, it's still good practice to use prepared statements.